# Seteo o borrado de Argumentos con Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragment

necesito ayuda, tengo dos clases en mi proyecto con java y Android studio pero no encuentro la forma de realizar un "Seteo" o "reset" a los argumentos de Bundle ya que mi validacion siempre es false.

```
if(getArguments().getBoolean("periodo", false))
{
//proceso dentro del if
}
```

Necesito ponerlo en true para que esa validación entre.

Comment: vos estas indicando que te devuelva falso por defecto, si no te gusta asi, podes poner que devuelva true por defecto. Podrias explicarte un poco mas? no veo ningun problema aquí

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es de que en algun momento de la aplicación ese valor se vuelve true, sin embargo no logro ver donde realiza ese proceso, como deberia buscarlo a nivel proyecto para ver donde cambia de false a true.

Comment: @ErickSilva y como puedo ponerle el valor true?

Comment: cuando creas el intent  intent.putExtra("periodo",true); o false, ahí lo seteas, el codigo de lo que pusiste es solo donde lo lees, no lo estas seteando en ningun lado? fijate en las respuestas que te dieron

Comment: Muchas gracias @ErickSilva ya logre ver donde se mandan esos argumentos y ya logre setearlos o mas bien asignarle nuevos datos a la key, te agradezco.

Answer (score 2):

En tu primera actividad debes de mandar un valor a tu segunda actividad:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,SegundaActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("periodo",true);
 startActivity(intent);  //aqui vas a tu segunda Actividad
```

Ahora para obtener ese valor en tu segunda actividad:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

boolean periodo = bundle.getBoolean("periodo",false); //en caso que no este definido que tome el valor false

if(periodo)
    {
       boolean ba = bundle.getBoolean("periodo",false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la que obtienes siempre false se debe a que este es el valor predeterminado en caso de no obtener valor, por lo tanto no estas obteniendo un valor para "periodo".

Si estas enviando en un bundle los valores, es muy importante saber que estos valores deben ser recibidos únicamente dentro de `onCreate()` de tu Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...

    if(getArguments().getBoolean("periodo", false))
    {
    //proceso dentro del if
    }

...
... 
}
```